# Compiling an Angular 9 library with enableIvy: false gives an error

Tags: angular

I'm compiling a library with Angular 9/ng-packagr and it works. But if I change in `angularCompilerOptions` and disable Ivy `"enableIvy": false` then I get the following error:

> ERROR: Unexpected value 'OtherLibModule in .../node_modules/other-lib-module/other-lib-module.d.ts' imported by the module 'MyModule in my-project/projects/my-lib/src/app/my.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

`OtherLibModule` is another library that I created, built with Angular 9 and `"enableIvy": false`.

Comment: Is your other library in the same project or its in different angular project?

Comment: In a different Angular project and I'm including it from npm repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that `public-api.ts` in `otherlib` was exporting the folder, not the barrel file (index). So I changed

```
export * from "./lib";
```

to

```
export * from "./lib/index";
```

in `public-api.ts` and it worked.
The problem was that the generated `otherlib-metadata.json` was not including all the required metadata.

There's also a reported issue on this matter https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/355. I cannot believe it's not solved even more than two years later.